# why my program showing ""pyroute2.netlink.exceptions.NetlinkError: (1, 'Operation not permitted') while disconnecting the wifi

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to disconnect a open wifi whose SSID is "Umar" (open network). After running with "sudo python3 disconnect.py wlp3s0" i am getting the error like "(-1 Operation not permitted)"
please help to solve this issue

```
import sys
#import logging
from pyroute2 import IPRoute
from pyroute2.iwutil import IW
from pyroute2.netlink import NLM_F_ACK
from pyroute2.netlink import NLM_F_REQUEST
from pyroute2.netlink import NLM_F_DUMP
from pyroute2.netlink.nl80211 import nl80211cmd
from pyroute2.netlink.nl80211 import NL80211_NAMES

ifname = sys.argv[1]

iw = IW()

ip = IPRoute()
ifindex = ip.link_lookup(ifname=ifname)[0]
ip.close()
ssid = b"Umar"

msg = nl80211cmd()
msg['cmd'] = NL80211_NAMES['NL80211_CMD_DISCONNECT']
msg['attrs'] = [['NL80211_ATTR_IFINDEX', ifindex]]
dump = iw.nlm_request(msg,msg_type=iw.prid,msg_flags=NLM_F_REQUEST | NLM_F_ACK)
print ("disconnect {}".format(dump))   
iw.close()
```

Thanks in advance